# Behaviour of setTimeout Inside console.log

Tags: javascript

I am executing the following code snippet on browser console.

```js
console.log(
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('a');
},200));
```

This gives me two outputs. First output is a random number(that is what i thought) and second is `a`. While I understand that the second output is normal, what is the first random number that is being generated in console.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MDN:

The returned timeoutID is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to setTimeout(); this value can be passed to clearTimeout() to cancel the timeout.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Return_value

The 8 you are seeing is the return value of the call to setTimeout, which is passed to console.log and output.

Answer (score 4):

The other number that is being logged is the return value of `setTimeout` function, which is the id for the timer, which can be used to clear the timer. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) for details